# the difference between the up and down methods in the migration file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-migration

i'm learning asp.net mvc 
when i add a migration to my project it add two files with three methods (seed, up and down).

i don't understand what is the difference between the up and down methods 
can you explain it for me ?

these are my up and down methods :
what does this mean !!

```
 public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Projets", "Description", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Projets", "UtilisateurID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Projets", "etat", c => c.Int());
            CreateIndex("dbo.Projets", "UtilisateurID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Projets", "UtilisateurID", "dbo.Utilisateurs", "UtilisateurID", cascadeDelete: true);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Projets", "UtilisateurID", "dbo.Utilisateurs");
            DropIndex("dbo.Projets", new[] { "UtilisateurID" });
            AlterColumn("dbo.Projets", "etat", c => c.String());
            DropColumn("dbo.Projets", "UtilisateurID");
            DropColumn("dbo.Projets", "Description");
        }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DB Migrations make changes to your database to reflect the changes made to the Entity Framework Model. These changes are added to the database with the `Up` method.

When you want to rollback a change (e.g. by rolling back a changeset in TFS or Git), the changes in the database have to be rolled back also because otherwise your Entity Framework model is out-of-sync with the database. This is what the `Down` method is for. It undo's all changes to the database that were done when the `Up` method was run against the database.

The `Seed` method gives you the ability to `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete` data which is sometimes needed when you change the model of the database. So the `Seed` method is optional and only necessary when you need to modify existing data or add new data to make the model working.